# How to solve this sum problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

[image]

For the first radical section.

$$\sqrt{1\times 2\times 3\times 4 + 1} - 1 = 1 + 3 + 1 - 1= 5 - 1 = 4$$

The second radical section.

$$(\sqrt{2\times 3\times 4\times 5 + 1}) = 4 = 4 + 6 + 1 - 4 = 7$$

The third radical (not shown)

$$\sqrt{3\times 4\times 5\times 6 + 1} - 9 = 9 + 9 + 1 - 9 = 10$$

If $x$ is considered. Then:

$$\sqrt{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) + 1} - x^2 = 3x + 1$$

I need to find:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{97} 3n + 1$$

$$=3\sum_{n=1}^{97} n + 97$$

$$= 3\cdot 97 \cdot 49 + 97 = 14 356$$

Comment: Are you assuming $x=1$ here?

Comment: No, I did a summation?

Comment: But how do you get $\sqrt{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot x^3+1}-1 $ to be 4 except by setting $x=1$? I see that @AMPerrine has edited the $x$s into multiplication signs, but they remain clearly and unambiguously $x$s in the original image.

Comment: In the original image, the $\mathrm{x}$'s under the radicals are not the same as the $x$'s in the hint (except for one stray $x$). It seems pretty clear from the hint that the intention is to indicate multiplication of four consecutive integers under the radical.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, for each radical it is different. for the first I set $x=1$, for the second $x=2$, ..... Then I got a general expression for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your sum up:

$$3\sum\limits_{n=1}^{97}n + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{97}1$$

$$3 {97 \choose 2} + 97$$

Comment: (+1), how did you get the combinatoric sum?

Comment: It's a fairly common identity, though you can prove by induction that the sum 1+2+...+n = n(n-1)/2 = n choose 2